# is it possible to install BOTH Zorin OS and MX-19.4 OS on THE SAME MACHINE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, debian

I have an old dell laptop that I recently installed zorin os on, and I have been told that since I am a newcomer to Linux, I should try out different distros to find one that suits my needs best.  I am wondering if I can install MX-19.4 os on my hard drive as well, do I need to partition my hard drive, should I leave mx-19,4 on the usb and just run it from there, and any how to's.
I appreciate any and all responses!!  Will provide any specs, just ask for them, and I might need instructions on where/how to find them.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple operating systems on one machine. It's as simple as shrinking the drive to make some space for the new OS (since you're on Zorin, the GParted tool may help) and then installing it on the free space you just created. Be careful, however, as you could lose your data. Make sure to do a backup before doing any partitioning. If you're using an EFI system, make sure to use the same `/boot/` partition on both systems, otherwise you could brick your system